# Rails emails SMTP validator gem high error rate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, email-validation

For context: I already have a regex for format validation and MX check, and would like to add a layer of SMTP validation. I have tried 2 gems: [email_verifier](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier) and [Truemail](https://github.com/rubygarage/truemail), none of which seem to perform well. For example, Truemail gem: tested on 1081 valid emails (verified by sending a link and have the users click), 171 came out invalid => ~15% fail rate for various reasons: the mail server blocks SMTP call resulting in an error code, timeout (when I already configured the timeout limit to be 10s), some emails need to be verified twice to return true, etc.

I was wondering if there's a way to appropriately do emails SMTP validation in RoR, or should I resolve to other paid services ([Snov](https://snov.io/) , [Truemail](https://truemail.io/) , etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that trying to connect directly to the smtp servers of the destination email domains from your Rails web server resulted in those servers rejecting your connection attempt as spam.

How were the 1081 valid emails sent originally? Most web applications don't send email directly from the Rails application server connecting to an SMTP server, but rather relaying through an SMTP relay or service such as AWS SES, Sendgrid, Mailchimp, etc. Those services would be configured better with correct SPF and DKIM DNS records for the IP addresses sending on behalf of the origin address and also likely have better reputations for the IP addresses they are originating from.